# Quicksort with Lists in C++

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, iterator, quicksort

I am working on a comparison for how different data structures effect the performance of an algorithm. I am trying to get the "List" data structure to work with Quicksort. When I try to run it however, my application crashes and gives me the error "list iterator not derefencable". Anyone know what could be going wrong? It is quite possible that there is some kind of iteration problem, because I am very unfamiliar with it.

```
void quickSortList(List& arr, int left, int right, int trialnr)
{// prepare iterators
    list<int>::iterator i = arr.begin();
    while(*i != left)
    {
        i++;
    }
    list<int>::iterator j = arr.end();
    while (*j != right)
    {
        j--;
    }
    int pivot = *i + *j / 2;

// inititate partitioning while the values on both left and right are not equal
while (*i <= *j)
{
    while (*i < pivot)
    {
        i++;
    }
    while (*j > pivot)
    {
        j--;
    }
    if (*i <= *j)
    {
        // while partitioning is in process, swap the corresponding arrays
        swap(i, j);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

// repeat the process until the array is sorted
if (left < *j)
{
    quickSortList(arr, left, right, trialnr);
}
if (*i < right)
{
    quickSortList(arr, left, right, trialnr);
}
}
```

Comment: What are `left` and `right`? And the `trialnr` which you don't use?

Comment: There are too many issues for a proper answer. I think you're confusing indexes with elements. Sort a `list<string>` instead. (You're definitely confusing iterators with elements.)

Comment: You're dereferencing the `end()` iterator (`while(*j != right)`)

Comment: Sorry trialnr shouldn't even be there anymore I made a mistake...left and right refer to the outmost values of the list (initially just the values of list.begin() / list.end() ). @0x499602D2 what do you mean by this and how do I fix it? Im thinking that maybe instead of integers i could just pass the iterators as a variable through the function? I am already convinced that solving this algorithm via lists is very inconvenient....Maybe I should rethink and restart the issue - perhaps closing this thread and seeing how far I can get with the newly obtained knowledge.